# Brahmanda and Pindanda

Tags: puranas, universe

I recently heard from a noted guru that the entire Brahmanda can be stored in Pindanda. How is this possible, any enlightenment is appreciated.

Basically he is saying the entire Macrocosm can be stored in Microcosm.
Is this just a statement on the philosophical level or it has some more meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Pindanda(Microcosm) is a reflection of Brahmanda(Macrocosm) as explained in [Uttara Geeta](https://cdn.website-editor.net/e4d6563c50794969b714ab70457d9761/files/uploaded/UttaraGita_BKLaheri.pdf), a conversation between Krishna and Arjuna

Chapter 2

> 9. Know by the process of Anvaya and Vyatireka that **the Atman which pervades the whole body is beyond the the three states of
>      consciousness - waking, dreaming and dreamless sleep.**
> 10. He who has been able to dwell with his mind for one moment on a single point (i.e., to perceive the Light of Caitanya) frees himself
>       from the sins of his past hundred births.
> 11. On the right side spreads the Pingalã Nãdi (i.e., from the sole of the right foot right up to the top of the head where the Sahasrãra
>       exists), it is bright and shining like a great circle of Fire (or the
>       Sun); this product of virtue (Pingalã) is called the vehicle of the
>       devas. (Meaning, that those who can fix their mind in this Nãdi, can
>       journey through the sky like Devas; therefore it is called the
>       "Deva-Yãna" or the vehicle of the Devas.)
> 12. On the left side stretches forth the Ida (i.e., from the sole of the left foot up to the Sahasrãra at the top of the head), the
>       brightness of this Nãdi is comparatively less, like the disk or circle
>       of the Moon; it dwells with the breath of the left nostril and it is
>       called the vehicle of the Pitrs. (Meaning, that those who can fix
>       their mind in this Nãdi, can ascend the Pitr Loka and no further;
>       hence it is called "Pitr-Yãna" or the vehicle of the Pitrs.)
>
> 13 & 14. Like the backbone of a Veena, or harp, the long tract of bone
>   with many joints that stretches from the seat right up to the head of
>   a human being is called the Meru-Danda (spinal cord). There is a
>   minute aperture or hole that passes right through this Meru-Danda from
>   the Mulãdhãra to the head; it is through this hole that there passes a
>   Nãdi which the yogis called the Brahma-Nãdi or Susumnã.
>
> 15. Susumnã is a fine nerve that passes between the Idã and Pingalã. From this Susumnã all the JnãnaNãdis (sensory nerves) take their
>       birth: hence it is called the Jnãna-Nãdi.
> 16. The Sun, the Moon, and the other Devatas, the fourteen Lokas of Bhur, Bhuvar, etc., the ten directions,East, West, etc., the sacred
>       places, the seven oceans,the Himãlaya and other mountains, the seven
>       Islands of Jambu, etc., the seven sacred rivers, Gangã, etc., the four
>       Vedas, all the sacred philosophies, the sixteen vowels and twenty-four
>       consonants,the Gãyatri and other sacred Mantras, the eighteen Purãnas
>       and all the Upa-Purãnas included, the three Gunas, Mahat itself, the
>       root of the Jîvas, the Jîvas and their Atman, the ten breaths, the
>       whole world, in fact, consisting of all these, exists in the Susumnã.
>
> [As all outward objects that are cognizable by the human senses are
>   reflected in the Susumnã Nãdi, therefore the Rsis call this body the
>   "microcosm". For instance,when you see the sun, moon, or the stars,
>   you do not actually go near to them in order to see, but you see them
>   because they are reflected in your Susumnã Nãdi. If your mind had the
>   power to go out of your body, in order to see them, then you would be
>   able to see all and everything that lies in the "Royal Road", and in
>   such a case you would know all and every occurrence that takes place
>   in every quarter of this globe, nay, and somewhere else, in this vast
>   universe.]
>
> 17. As various Nãdis have sprung up from the Susumnã, the receptacle of the Inner soul of all Jîvas - and are stretched out in all
>       directions of the physical body, therefore it is considered like a
>       huge tree reversed. The Tattva-Jnãnins alone are able to walk on every
>       branch of this tree by the help of PrãnaVãyu.
> 18. In this human body there exist seventy-two thousand Nãdis which admit of sufficient space for entrance into them through Vãyu; the
>       Yogins alone become acquainted with the true nature of these Nãdis by
>       the virtue of their Yoga-Karma.
> 19. Having closed up the nine portals of the body, and being acquainted with the source and nature of the Nãdis that stretch up and
>       down the seats of the several organs of sense, the Jîva, rising to the
>       state of superior knowledge with the aid of the Life-Breath, attains
>       Moksa.
> 20. On the left side of this Susumnã, and near the point of the nose, there exists the Indra-Loka by name called Amarãvatî; and the bight
>       luminous sphere that exists in the eyes is known by the name of
>       AgniLoka.
> 21. Near the right ear exists the Yama-Loka (the place of death) known by the name of Samyamanî, and on its side exists the sphere of the
>       Nairrta Deva, called by the name of Nairrta-Loka.
> 22. On the west (i.e., of the Susumnã),and situated in the back, there exists the sphere of Varuna called by the name of Vibhãvarî: and on
>       the side of the ears, the sphere is known as Gandhavatî This is the
>       seat of the Vãyu.
> 23. On the north side of Susumnã, extending from the throat up to the left ear, and in the sphere of Kubera, known by the name of
>       Pushpavatî, exists the Candra-Loka.
> 24. The lower portion, or the sole of the foot, is called Atala; the upper portion, or the top, is called Vitala; the upper part of the
>       joint between the leg and foot (i.e., the ankle) is called Nitala, and
>       knee (Jangha) is called Sutala.
> 25. The lower portion of the thigh (Jãnu) is called Mahãtala; the upper portion of it (Uru) is called Rasãtala, and the loin (Kati) is
>       termed Talãtala. In this way it is proper to know the seven Pãtãlas
>       that exist in the human body.
> 26. In the Pãtãlas where the serpents live in coils, and below the navel, is the place known by the name of Bhogîndra; this dreadful
>       place, like a burning Hell and Doomsday Fire, is termed Mahãpãtãla; in
>       this sphere, the eternal known by the name of Jîva, displays itself in
>       serpentine coils like a circle.
> 27. Bhur-Loka exists in the navel; in the armpit [ This localizes a great nervous and magnetic centre that directs every motion of the
>       arms.] exists the Bhuvar, while the Svarga-Loka, with the sun, moon
>       and stars, dwells in the heart.
> 28. In the heart (of the person who thus imagines) dwells the Mahar-Loka, the Jana-Loka exists in the throat, the Tapo-Loka between
>       the two eyebrows, while the Satya-Loka exists in the head.
>
> 32 & 33. This Brahmãnda shaped Earth [ That is, like the egg of
>   Brahmã.] dissolves itself into Water, the Water is dried up by fire,
>   the Air swallows up the Fire, and the Akãsa drinks the Air in turn;
>   but the Akãsa itself is assimilated in the Mind, the Mind in Buddhi,
>   the Buddhi in Ahankãra, the Ahankãra in Citta, and the Citta in
>   Ksetrajna (i.e., Atman or Spirit).
>
> 34. **The Yogins who contemplate me with one mind as "I am He" are saved from the sins collected during a hundred millions of Kalpas.**
> 35. **As the Akãsa of the pot is absorbed in the Mahãkãsa when the pot is broken, so also the ignorance bound Jîvãtman is absorbed in the
>       Paramãtman when ignorance is destroyed.**
> 36. He who has been able to acquire the knowledge of the Tattvas that the 
>       Jîvãtman is absorbed in the Paramãtman, even as the Akãsa of the
>       Pot is absorbed in the Mahãkãsa, becomes undoubtedly free from the
>       chain of ignorance, and goes into the sphere of the Light of Supreme
>       Knowledge and Wisdom.

Comment: Good!  Brahman, by Hinduism scriptures means "that which expands or grows". Let's expand our imagination a bit. Actually, Brahman does so by eating food (Refer to Purusha Sukta). So, Technically In order to expand or change the Universe, Brahman should enter the body containing the Universe absorb it and eat food and Grow the Universe. Now, realize why an Avatar is required. Questions. 1) What should happen for Pitrs to Ascend? 2) What should happen for All the 14 lokas(Worlds) to Ascend? you certainly don't want to repeat the cycle, And loka no.26 is kindda miserable!

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman Brahman is infinite static Shiva space and cant move or expand without Shakti/Prana/time. Brahman expands by self realization of his children or himself like Shakti/Gotra expands on earth by Man(form of Shiva)-Woman(form of Shakti) union. Just read Einstein's Space-Time theory of relativity and replace Space with Brahman/consciousness and Time with Shakti/energy.       
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saundarya_Lahari  In fact, it opens with the assertion that Only when Shiva is united with Shakti does he have the power to create.

Comment: “Your own Self-Realization is the greatest service you can render the world.” - Ramana Maharshi

Answer (score 4):

Many Hindu scriptures state what that Guruji has stated. That there is nothing in this universe miniature of which is not found in the human body.

The 2nd Chapter of the Yogic treatise [Shiva Samhita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Samhita) states:

> 1. **In this body, the mount Meru – i.e., the vertebral column – is surrounded by seven islands; there are rivers, seas, mountains,
>      fields; and lords of the fields too.**
> 2. **There are in it seers and sages; all the stars and planets as well. There are sacred pilgrimages, shrines; and presiding deities of the
>      shrines.**
> 3. **The sun and moon, agents of creation and destruction, also move in it. Ether, air, water and earth are also there.**
>
> (2) The Nerve Centers.
>
> **4. All the beings that exist in the three worlds are also to be found in the body; surrounding the Meru they are engaged in their
>   respective functions.**
>
> 5. (But ordinary men do not know it). He who knows all this is a Yogi; there is no doubt about it.
> 6. In this body, which is called Brahmanda (microcosm, literally the mundane egg), there is the nectar-rayed moon, in its proper place, on
>      the top of the spinal cord, with eight Kalas (in the shape of a
>      semi-circle).

But it is also a fact, as stated in one of the verses given above, that not everyone is capable of realizing the existence of the whole universe within one's body. Only Yogis, Satgurus are truly aware of that fact.

Comment: 1) "In this body, which is called "Brahmanda" , shouldn't this be Pindanda? 2) I bow down to your knowledge of Hinduism and Math! In your opinion, what part of the Universe should be stored in Biological beings and What part should be non-biological :-)

Comment: 3) Which part of the body will you be able to fit Electrical appliances of the entire Universe :-)

Comment: You break down the appliances and then see what they reduce to .. all of those parts will be somewhere in the body .. Btw where did you know about my knowledge on Maths? I never post anything about that. @GopalAnantharaman